# Kafka Broker Health Metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics

I am looking for JMX metric(s) for Kafka Broker [Not more than 1 or 2, if possible] which at a high level can identify the health of the cluster? I have referred to the list compiled by datadog and confluent, but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Confluent blogs mention the most critical metrics to gather...

Answer (score 2):

Some things I'd consider indicative of the health of the cluster are as follows:

**Offline/Under Replicated Partitions**: This is a good indicator as to whether all the nodes in a cluster are even online. If one goes offline, you will almost certainly see some under-replication, and if several are offline, you might even see some offline partitions.

**Active Controller**: If this keeps changing, then it means that the cluster is potentially unstable. The controller should not change regularly; if it does, then something is wrong with your cluster.

**Bytes In/Out**: These show that your cluster is able to send and receive data. If these are lower than you'd expect, then it might imply that the cluster is undergoing some sort of network issue which would possibly impact the cluster health.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also disk space and general network bandwidth overlaid with Kafka bytes, as a system metric

Comment: Thanks Simon and @cricket_007... I already have all of them... Bytes In/Out gives me the granularity at Topic level as well, which yes, is a measure of stability/health; but I was looking at core Broker metrics where I wasn't sure ActiveController-Count alone can suffice. The point of changing Active controller is good and the Offline Partitions as well. Thanks again!